# Renaming/Copying file with complicated name requirements

Tags: powershell

I have to create a script that searches for file, takes part of the folder name and move the file to a new location with that new name.

I am planning to use powershell for this but would be up willing to look for other options. This used for millions of files.

Example 1
sourcefolder\a\b\test_123456\example.txt   -> \destinationfolder\example_123456.txt

Problem is I don't know how many folders deep the file is and the amount of folder name changes, I need everything after the last _

Example 2
sourcefolder\a\b\c\test_test_1234\example.txt   -> \destinationfolder\example_1234.txt

I am researching how to script and will update question when I when I have some progress

Comment: if you use  `Get-ChildItem` it will be rather slow. however, the properties of each file will include the parent dir, so you can use that to build your new file name.

Comment: To search for the correct file I would suggest regex.

Comment: Be sure to use `-LiteralPath` instead of `-Path` to avoid any unforeseen issues with files or folders that may contain special characters.

Answer (score 0):

[FileInfo objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo) include many properties. One of these is the `.Directory` property which returns the directory (as [DirectoryInfo object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory)) that represents the parent folder the file is in. This Directory also has properties, like `.Name`.

You can use this like below:

```
$sourceFolder      = 'D:\Test'     # the root folder to search through
$destinationFolder = 'X:\Archive'  # the destinationpath for the moved files

# make sure the destination folder exists
$null = New-Item -Path $destinationFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

# get a collection of FileInfo objects
# if you need more file extensions like both .txt and .log files, replace -Filter '*.txt' with -Include '*.txt', '*.log'
# this will be slower than using -Filter though..
$filesToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File -Filter '*.txt' -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.Directory.Name -like '*_*'}

# using a foreach(..) is a bit faster than 'ForEach-Object'
foreach ($file in $filesToMove) {
    # get the last part after '_' of the parent directory name
    $suffix = ($file.Directory.Name -split '_')[-1] 
    # combine to create the new path and filename
    $target = Join-Path -Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath ('{0}_{1}{2}' -f $file.BaseName, $suffix, $file.Extension)
    $file | Move-Item -Destination $target -Force -WhatIf
}
```

Take off the `WhatIf` safety switch if you are satisfied what is displayed on screen about what *would* be moved is correct.

---

You don't even need the foreach loop because Move-Item can handle a scriptblock as parameter for the Destination like this:

```
$sourceFolder      = 'D:\Test'     # the root folder to search through
$destinationFolder = 'X:\Archive'  # the destinationpath for the moved files

# make sure the destination folder exists
$null = New-Item -Path $destinationFolder -ItemType Directory -Force

# get a collection of FileInfo objects
# if you need more file extensions like both .txt and .log files, replace -Filter '*.txt' with -Include '*.txt', '*.log'
# this will be slower than using -Filter though..
$filesToMove = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File -Filter '*.log' -Recurse | 
                Where-Object {$_.Directory.Name -like '*_*'} |
                Move-Item -Destination {
                    $suffix = ($_.Directory.Name -split '_')[-1]
                    Join-Path -Path $destinationFolder -ChildPath ('{0}_{1}{2}' -f $_.BaseName, $suffix, $_.Extension)
                } -Force
```

Here, the `$_` [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7#_) is used instead of a variable you define in a foreach loop.

P.S. If you only need files from subfolders with a name ending in `_` followed by **numbers** only as opposed to names like `sub_folder`, change the Where-Object {...} clause in the code to

```
Where-Object {$_.Directory.Name -match '_\d+$'}
```